# Byte[] is not decoding to bitmap properly

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, bitmap

Firstly, I am storing a .png to a mySQL database.  I do this by first making the .png a bitmap and then making it Base64 by using the following method:

```
private String prepPictureForDb(Bitmap bm){
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

I then store the Base64 String into my database in a varchar(3000) column (which I realize may not be the best way to store this but from what I understand it still should work).

When I retrieve this String from the database via php, I use this code:

```
<?php
    //load and connect to MySQL database stuff
    require("config.inc.php");
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        //gets user's info based off of a username.
        $query = "SELECT isAdmin, username, lastLogin, phone, email, image FROM Vamoose.user_accounts WHERE first_name = :first AND last_name = :last";
        $query_params = array(':first' => $_POST['first'], ':last' => $_POST['last']);
        try {
            $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        }
        catch (PDOException $ex) {
            // For testing, you could use a die and message.
            //die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
            //or just use this use this one to product JSON data:
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "Database Error. Please Try Again!";
            die(json_encode($response));
        }
        //fetching all the rows from the query
        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        if ($row) {
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["isAdmin"] = $row["isAdmin"];
            $response["username"] = $row["username"];
            $response["lastLogin"] = $row["lastLogin"];
            $response["phone"] = $row["phone"];
            $response["email"] = $row["email"];
            $response["image"] = base64_encode($row["image"]);
        }else{
            $response["success"] = 0;
        }
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

As you can see I do `base64_encode($row["image"]);`and then `echo json_encode($response);`

Back in Android Studio, I decode the String by using the following code:

```
String image = json.getString("image").toString();
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(this.image, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

The issue is that `bm` is NULL

NOTE*: I have scoured Stack Overflow for threads on this topic and found numerous matches. However, none of them seem to related to my problem specifically.

Comment: The bitmap is already converted to base64 string and stored in the database, right? Why do you call `base64_encode($row["image"]);` again after fetch it from database?

Comment: good point.  When change `base64_encode($row["image"]);` to `$row["image"]`, the string I get back form the database contains chars like '/' and '+' and by byte[] has negative numbers in it.  I do now know much about image encoding/decoding but from what I understand, it is not bing decoding properly as it shouldn't have these chars in the string.

Comment: Figured it out.  When I changed the mySQL column datatype from varchar to text, it worked.  Probably has something to do with the way varchars are stored.